# Volley:Cannot refer to the non-final local variable in android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have a following method, which submits `http` request using Volley:

```
private boolean SaveInformationToServer(Information information)
{

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {                           
                       try{
                            return true;
                       }
                       catch (Exception ex){
                          return false;
                       }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

I require this method to return either `true` or `false` but currently it's giving error `void method cannot return a value`. I tried a variable, then I got `cannot refer to the non-final local variable inside an inner class`.

How can I make this method return a `boolean` value to its caller?

Comment: Use a callback. Google for 'android asynchronous callback return value' or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `onResponse` is void plus it's a function of an anonymous class so you can't return value from anonymous class to your caller of volley request.

You can create your function can call them on volley response and put your code to execute the result instead of keeping a flag, this will keep your code more structural and readable(you can also set you flags in your onSuccess).

```
void onSuccess(String response){
// do what you want to do
}
void onError(VolleyError error){
// do what you want to do 
}   
 private void SaveInformationToServer(Information information)
        {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {                           
                        onSuccess(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 onError(error);
            }
        });

        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```